# mysql group by, two conditions, limit 1

Tags: mysql, sql, view, group-by

I would like to select the oldest event date for all tickets.  I created this query "tixdate" view in mysql (that I use for other purposes) and it sorts the records by ticket number, then by eventdate.  This view looks like this:

```
EventDate  | Ticket                                    
2018-02-25 | 998<br>
2018-02-25 | 998<br>
2018-02-25 | 998<br>
2018-02-11 | 998<br>
2018-02-11 | 998<br>
2018-02-04 | 998<br>
2018-02-04 | 998<br>
2018-02-03 | 998<br>
2018-02-03 | 998<br>
2018-01-27 | 998<br>
2018-01-27 | 998<br>
2018-01-21 | 998<br>
2018-01-21 | 998<br>
2018-01-14 | 998<br>
2018-01-14 | 998<br>
2018-01-13 | 998<br>
2018-01-13 | 998<br>
2018-01-07 | 998<br>
-----------------------------------
```

I created a new mysql view to list only the oldest event date:

```
    SELECT
     'audTix` AS `audTix`,
     `audDt` AS `audDt`
    FROM
     `tixdate`
    GROUP BY
     `audTix`
    ORDER BY
     `audDt` DESC
```

which produced one record:

```
2018-01-13 | 998
```

But it should have selected the 2018-02-25 date.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter whether you select from a table or a view, the data is considered unordered. So even though your view `tixdate` contains an `ORDER BY` clause, this gets ignored once you select from it. (More precise: the DBMS is free to ignore it; and it should do so in order to select data more quickly.)

Any way, even if this were not the case, then your query still wouldn't work. You group by `audTix`, so you get one result row per `audTix`. But you select `audDt` which is an `audDt` belonging to the `audTix`. You don't say which (e.g. the minimum, maximum or average), so MySQL translates this to `ANY_VALUE(audDt)`. You then sort the results by `audDt`, but as these are arbitrarily picked, this makes no sense. (And if your table only contains one `audTix`, you only get one result row, so there is nothing to sort obviously.)

What you want is the maximum date, so select it:

```
SELECT audTix, MAX(audDt)
FROM tixdate
GROUP BY audTix
ORDER BY audTix;
```

If you want to order by date, then that's `ORDER BY MAX(audDt)` instead. If you only want the one `audTix` with the latest date, you'd `ORDER BY MAX(audDt) DESC LIMIT 1`.

And if you only want the oldest event date from all records (without selecting the associated `audTix`), that's

```
SELECT MAX(audDt) FROM tixdate;
```

of course.

(And you can remove the `ORDER BY` clause from your view `tixdate`. As mentioned, an `ORDER BY` clause in a view makes no sense.)

Comment: THanks much!  Using MAX() function works great.  I didn't know that db ignores ignores the order by.